# Visual Studio - Exclude from solution large folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How can I exclude from VS solution explorer an extremely large folder? If I right click and select exclude from project then VS crashes. How can I do it manually?

Comment: This question seems so vague, can you please post some pictures related to your question

Comment: You go to Solution Explorer, select any folder from the solution, right click it, select Exclude from Project, the folder will be excluded/hidden, files won't be taken into consideration. Example you have a folder called: Models with one class in it that has an error. If you exclude the folder it will exclude also the class. When you build it will succeed because it ignores the class that has errors from the Models folder. Now I have a large folder, large by the amount of files, if I exclude the folder, VS crashes. How can I do it manually/different way?

Comment: Yeah I know that part, but VS won't break down because of it. That's why asking you to post the pictures in your questions. anyways nvm, somebody else may suggest you some solution without it :)

Comment: The image is like this: VS in No Response mode, frozen for 10 min... I gave up and used task manager to kill it.

Comment: I face the same issue. If a folder has alot of files (say images), VS just keep excluding it for hours. And ultimately, have to just kill it using task manager.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with VS2015 while trying to exclude a large folder with 2000+ files. The IDE became unresponsive / hang.

Solution :
Close the solution. Manually edit the .PROJ file and delete the file entries. Lines like **Compile Include="Folder\FileName.cs"**.

---

Details:

Turns out FOR EVERY FILE being excluded, it was scanning [**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tool\Rule Sets\ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset**], and reading all the DLL files being referenced by the project, once.

Renaming the FXCop / Static Analysis folders makes no difference to speed.

Using SysInternals Process Monitor, it takes around 0.3 seconds for each file to be excluded. So excluding 2000 files took about 10 minutes, which was excatly when VS IDE became responsive again.

On the other hand, INCLUDING the same folder into the solution only takes 8 secs.